# What is this Java syntax [ 1.class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument ]?

Tags: java, syntax

does anybody know the Java syntax `1.class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument`?

The eclipse shows the error as below:

```
Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error on token "1.", . expected after this token
- Syntax error on token "class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument", delete 
 this token
- Syntax error on token "1.", . expected after this token
- Syntax error on token "class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument", delete 
 this token
- Syntax error on token "class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument", delete 
 this token
```

Code:

```
package noNamespace;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoader;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public abstract interface PrintAgreementDocument extends XmlObject
{
    public static final SchemaType type = (SchemaType)XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(
        (1.class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument == null ? 
            (1.class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument = 1.class$("noNamespace.PrintAgreementDocument")) 
            : 1.class$noNamespace$PrintAgreementDocument).getClassLoader(), 
                 "schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s95BAEA12C764073D07067A316EACE")
                     .resolveHandle("printagreement7eb6docty");
```

The code as below is at the same class

Code:

```
  public static final class Factory
  {
    public static PrintAgreementDocument newInstance()
    {
      return    (PrintAgreementDocument)XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader().newInstance(PrintAgreementDocument.type, null);
    }
```

Comment: Is this generated code? Is the source it is generated from valid?

Comment: Is this decompiled code?

Comment: Not sure why 2 downvotes for this question

Comment: Where did this code come from?

Comment: This is not valid java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Java syntax - **All identifiers should begin with a letter (A to Z or a to z ), currency character ($) or an underscore (_)**

Comment: Hi xagyg, thank you for the answer. 
It is existed application. Also the jar was generated by other team. At The QA and production server, it works well. So I assume the jar is OK.
However, at my development environment machine

PrintAgreementDocument agreementDoc = PrintAgreementDocument.Factory.newInstance();    throw NoClassDefFoundError excepetion.  

The application server is Weblogic 9